# How to find correlations of the features in a dataframe? The features are of mixed types (nominal, ordinal, discrete, and continuous)

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, scikit-learn, data-preprocessing, pandas

I am working with python using pandas, and seaborn libraries.
I have a dataframe, that I am using for some machine learning. My dataframe has a **target** variable, along with several **other features**.
Suppose the following data dictionary

| Name | Type | Dtype |
| --- | --- | --- |
| f1 | ordinal | int |
| f2 | ordinal | int |
| f3 | nominal | categorical |
| f4 | nominal | categorical |
| f5 | discrete | int |
| f6 | discrete | int |
| f7 | continuous | int |
| f8 | continuous | int |
| target | nominal | int |

Now on this dataset, I wish to see a correlation matrix, in order to check which features are colinear to each other as well as which features strongly associate to the target variable.

Please guide me with the following questions:

1. Is using a correlation matrix (with either of the methods such as **Spearsman, Kendall, or Pearson**) a right approach on this dataset? These correlation methods come from `pandas.DataFrame.corr()`
2. Does the choice of using either of the above mentioned methods depend on the features OR on the target variable?
3. Do we also consider our target variable before making decision about correlation method? Suppose if my target was a continuous one? or even an ordinal one?

Answer (score 1):

Two things: First, correlation is not a good way to check for collinearity. There are collinearity diagnostics available for regression in R and SAS; I'd imagine they are in Python/Pandas as well. Look for condition indexes or variance inflation factors.

Collinearity is a relationship among any set of independent variables. You can have perfect collinearity with low correlation. For an extreme example, imagine that there are 10 IVs.  Nine of them are random and unrelated. The tenth is the sum of the other 9.

Second, if you do want correlations for some other reason, then which type of correlation you can do depends on the variable type.  With continuous variables you can use any of the methods, although they will do different things. With ordinal you should really only use a ranked method like Spearman's. And for nominal data, correlation doesn't exist (there are other measures of association).

Comment: VIF isn't standardized like correlations. In correlation I know lowest and highest values so its kinda more helpful. I know it can only handle colinearity (between pairs). To handle MC, I definitely go for VIF, or do a PCA. Is that correct?

Comment: Coming back to correlations, does it mean that I should plot two correlation matrices. One for my continuous variables and other for my ordinal variables. And for nominal ones, I should do something else. Please advice that as well

Comment: I prefer condition indexes for collinearity.  PCA doesn't do it. VIFs are OK. (My dissertation compared VIF and condition indexes and favored the latter).  For correlations, you could do one matrix (just with different correlations) or multiple matrices. For nominal-nominal you could use lambda.  Also see the association measures tag https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/association-measure